# Return single value from table with SQLite PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a table that stores the setting and its value what is the best way to retreve the values form the database?

Settings table is set out like this:

```
setting    value
 host       1.2.3.4
 port       1234
 user       me
 pass       cake
```

Eg:

```
$host = $db->query('SELECT value FROM settings where setting = "host" ');
print $host;
```

Comment: what do you actually want to do? and btw how can `setting = "host"`?

Comment: @Mr. Alien
I want to be able to get the value of host from the settings table (or any other setting).

Comment: your database design is actually wrong...

Comment: depends on you, are you having settings per user, or just these settings etc

Comment: These are global settings that will be used by all of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am Using PDO

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT value FROM settings where setting = :host');
$sth->bindValue(':host', $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$value = $sth->fetch();
return $value;
```

This is the recommended way now to react with database.